# Can I purchase an EV SSL for a single subdomain?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, mod-ssl

Hey everyone sorry for the noob question, I was getting different
answers on Google.

My question specifically is: Am I able to purchase a EV SSL for each
of my sub-domains.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No wildcards, but there's no reason you couldn't buy one for each subdomain individually.

Comment: Do you really need EV SSL?

Comment: No, but it looks cool.

Comment: I guess if you don't mind paying 2, 3, 4 times the price for "looking cool".

Comment: Sure don't mind at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Note that they must be Subject Alternative Name (SAN) and wildcards are not allowed.

> **9.2.2. Subject Alternative Name Extension**
>
> **Certificate field:** subjectAltName:dNSName
>
> **Required/Optional:** Required
>
> **Contents:** This extension MUST contain one or more host Domain Name(s) owned or controlled by the Subject and to be associated with
>   the Subject’s server. Such server MAY be owned and operated by the
>   Subject or another entity (e.g., a hosting service). Wildcard
>   certificates are not allowed for EV Certificates.

Source: [Guidelines For The Issuance And Management Of Extended Validation Certificates v. 1.6.6 (pdf)](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/EV-V1_6_6.pdf)